# Best Cassandra/Scylla configuration with single FE node

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, scylla

I'd like to have a simple Cassandra/Scylla cluster with two nodes, rf 2 so they both contain the same data. I want to expose one node to the internet (temporarily) behind NAT. The router has a dynamic IP which is resolved by a dynDNS on, let's say, `domain.my`.

[image]

The idea is quite simple: an app with the Java Driver connects to the back-end app through domain:port, which NAT routes to `c1`. Node `c2` works as backup and on internal network workloads.

I set it up and it works quite well, but the JavaDriver retrieves the internal topology and tries to connect also to node2 on x.x.x.02, which is obviously incorrect.

```
DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R) (com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core) version 4.17.0
Adding handler to invalidate cached prepared statements on type changes
Using native clock for microsecond precision
[s0|/x.x.x.2:9042]  Error while opening new channel (ConnectionInitException: [s0|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (STARTUP {CQL_VERSION=3.0.0, DRIVER_NAME=DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R), DRIVER_VERSION=4.17.0, CLIENT_ID=fa6fade1-58ca-4d73-b85b-2f316abf9d02}): failed to send request (java.nio.channels.NotYetConnectedException))
Connected to cluster: Uzz, with session: s0
Datacenter: datacenter1; Host: domain.my/<unresolved>:9042; Rack: rack1
Datacenter: datacenter1; Host: /x.x.x.2:9042; Rack: rack1
```

Is there any way to prevent that? I have explored to use an AddressTranslator to map both addresses to the public address but this does not work well with the key space:

```
Unexpected error while refreshing token map, keeping previous version (IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: Murmur3Token(-107948562044971185)=Node(endPoint=domain.my/<unresolved>:9042, hostId=15450683-e34b-475d-a393-ad25611398d8, hashCode=38b03e88) and Murmur3Token(-107948562044971185)=Node(endPoint=domain.my/<unresolved>:9042, hostId=15450683-e34b-475d-a393-ad25611398d8, hashCode=38b03e88))
```

Is this use case doable at all? Is there any better way?

### nodetool status

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  x.x.x.51   34.44 GB   256          ?       15450683-e34b-475d-a393-ad25611398d8  rack1
UN  x.x.x.100  34.5 GB    256          ?       6cad2ba2-b22e-4947-a952-dc65c616a08f  rack1

Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless
```

### application.properties

```
#
# DataStax Java Driver for Cassandra configuration file
datastax-java-driver.basic.config-reload-interval = 0
datastax-java-driver.advanced.protocol.version = V4
datastax-java-driver.advanced.netty.daemon = true
datastax-java-driver.advanced.metadata.schema.enabled = false
datastax-java-driver.advanced.address-translator.class = ste.uzz.store.CassandraAddressTranslator
datastax-java-driver.advanced.address-translator.public-address = uzz.fornari.net
```

Comment: how does your `application.conf` file and `nodetool status` output look like?

Comment: added in description

Comment: @Madhavan or anyone, any advise?

Comment: The driver will [always](https://docs.astra.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/address_resolution/) know the entire topology of the cluster (including all the datacenters) as soon as it connects to the initial contact points and establishes connectivity there. You could use [LBP](https://docs.astra.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/load_balancing/) & [connection pooling](https://docs.astra.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/pooling/) to control which datacenter/nodes it talks to.